# Create function with given number of input arguments

Tags: matlab, function, function-handle

Here's the situation:
I need to create a function that takes a function handle `fun` which is of *CONSTANT input-length* (that is `nargin(fun)>=0`), does some transformation on the inputs and then calls `fun`. 
Pseudo-Code:

```
function g = transformFun(fun)
n = nargin(fun);
g = @(v_1, ..., v_n) ...
%           ^ NOT REAL MATLAB - THE MAIN PROBLEM
    fun(someCalculationsWithSameSizeOfOutput(v_1,...v_n){:});
% CAN BE ACHIEVED WITH TEMPORARY CELL IN HELPER FUNCTION ^
end
```

Now the problem: the output function's handle (`g = transformFun(concreteFun)`) is then passed to other code that relies on the fact that the function is of  constant length (assumes `nargin(g)>=0`), thus a variable-input-length function is unacceptable (the "easy" solution).

This transformation is called with many functions with every possible number of arguments (`n` is unbounded), so covering a finite number of possibilities is also not possible.

Is there a (simple?) way to achieve that?

[I've searched the internet for a few hours and could only come up with a nasty hack involving the deprecated `inline` function, which I couldn't make work; maybe I have the wrong terminology].

Comment: Does `g` need to be able to be interrogated with `nargin`?

Comment: I think your wording is making the problem way more complicated. You want `fun` to be able to handle **variable** amount of inputs, not **constant**, right?

Comment: @Suever That's right

Comment: @AnderBiguri Sorry about that; `fun` is the input and can handle only finite amount, the problem is as `fun` varies so does this finite amount

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So typically you could use `varargin` to handle this sort of thing, but since you need `nargin(g)` to return the *actual* number of inputs it's a little trickier.

You could use `str2func` to create the anonymous function as a string and then convert it to a function handle.

```
% Create a list or arguments: x1, x2, x3, x4, ...
args = sprintf('x%d,', 1:nargin(func));
args(end) = '';

% Place these arguments into a string which indicates the function call
str = sprintf('@(%s)fun(someCalculationsWithSameSizeOfOutput(%s))', args, args);

% Now create an anonymous function from this string
g = str2func(str);
```

Based on the attrocity above, it may be worth considering an alternative way of dealing with your function handles.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank You!

Comment: It's communicating with other people's code so it's a little tricky, but I couldn't agree more